# Как задать прототип для объекта в Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, объекты, prototype, vue3

Нужно создать для объектов новый прототип. Пишу код а-ля:

```
Object.prototype.qwe = function() {
    console.log(1)
}
```

В результате в браузере получаю ошибки:

*Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "qwe". Expected , got Function.*

*Data property "qwe" is already defined in Props.*

*Unexpected error when starting the router: TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'catch' in undefined.*

Пробовала в разных местах создавать - в отдельном скрипте, в скрипте внутри App.vue, в хуках - результат тот же.
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь

Comment: К слову, для строк и массивов создаються прототипы нормально

Answer (score 0):

Ну я надеюсь вы в курсе что  `Object prototype is read-only, properties should not be added.`
По-этому сюда ->
[тыц](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)